# Force selection on previous cell with same dropdown list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, list, dropdownlist

My sheet has multiple cells with the same dropdown list.
The data for the dropdown list is also on this sheet (in a hidden column (H)).
So the dropdowns source =$H$1:$H$6

| A | B | C | D | H (data for dropdown) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Option A |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Option B |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Option C |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro A |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro B |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro C |

This is what I want to achieve:

If the user selects option B in C2, I want the cell on the left (B2 in this case) to simulate its selection to intro B. Like so:

| A | B | C | D | H (data for dropdown) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Option A |
| dropdown | Intro B | Option B | dropdown | Option B |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Option C |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro A |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro B |
| dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | dropdown | Intro C |

I don't know how to do this without putting some kind of formula in every cell like:
=IF(B1="Option A","Intro B",IF(B1="Option B","Intro B",IF(B1="Option C", "Intro C","")))
In this case this would be the formula for A1.

But even if that would work, I wonder if I should put a formula in the source of the dropdown list? Or is this something to achieve by adjusting the formula in every cell.

Oh and if an option is selected in colum A, there is no previous cell so it won't apply to column A.

Comment: Do you want people to be able to select an item in column B or do you want column B to be calculated based on the value in column C? Similarly, if someone selects a value in column B, what happens in column A? Is it calculated from the value in column B or is it selected from a drop-down? Further, if I select a value for C2, and B2 is calculated, is A2 also calculated based on the value in B2?

Comment: What do you want to happen if an "Intro" (say Intro C) is selected by a dropdown? Do you want the corresponding Option (in this case Option C) to appear in the cell immediately to the right (so that as in your description you end up with the Intro/Option pair in adjacent cells in the row with Intro to left and Option to right? If an Intro/Option pair is utilised do you permit dropdowns to be used elsewhere in the row or in any other row?

Comment: @DMM selecting An Intro option wouldn't cause any effect other than the cell getting that value 'intro C' for example. So it doesn't have to happen the other way around. And if a pair is made, it doesn't mean the pair cant be made in another column. Only column the pairing wouldnt go well would be A ;). Thanks for your time

Comment: @FlexYourData all columns would have the same cells with same dropdowns. If user selects option A in column C, only column B would het the intro A option.

Comment: Is Column B always dependent on Column C? If so, why does it need a drop-down?

Comment: You possibly want, `=IF(LEFT(B1,1)="O","Intro "&RIGHT(B1,1),"")` in cell A1 and then copy to remaining "dropdown" cells. In the data validation setting up the dropdowns you should check the "ignore blank" option.

Comment: @FlexYourData no column A tot D have the same dropdowns with data from column H. So in A, B,C,D you can select either a 'option' OR even an 'intro' but if the user would select 'option A B of C' I want the cell on the left of it to automatically change to matching 'Intro'

Comment: You can't put a formula in a cell and then also have a drop-down to allow a user to put a fixed value in the same cell. When the fixed value is selected, the formula would be overwritten.

Comment: @FlexYourData ok I'm still learning. Is this something i would have to put in the source of the data validation list?

Comment: There are a couple of difficulties. First, a cell can either be used for input (from the user) or for output (calculated by a formula). Without VBA, a cell cannot be both at the same time. So, separation of inputs from outputs might be a fruitful way forward - use one range for inputs and one for outputs. Second, the precise relationships between inputs and outputs is not clear - eg What happens if an input changes from say "Option A" to an empty cell, do both affected output cells change to displaying a blank? What happens if two adjacent input cells each show an option?

Comment: It is possible to put a formula in a drop-down but it needs to be specified as part of a comma-separated list of possibles in the data validation dialog,  rather than using a reference to a range containing the list of possibles. However, this does not particularly help since the dropdown now simply lists the available possibilities including any formula (such as =IF(...)) so the user is left to decide for each cell which value or formula should be used. In addition, the formula is specific to each cell with a dropdown so tedious to create and prone to error.

Comment: @DMM thank you for your time. I understand. Changing 'option A' to An empty cell would eventually have to check if theres an 'intro' before IT and empty that as well. But for now I thought I would Just ask this. So without VBA its not possible to say; Find all cells containing 'Option A' and put An 'intro A' to the left side of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With separation of inputs and outputs:

Inputs are in A1:D6 and outputs are in A11:D16

[image]

Input range has no formulae, just data validation in each cell using $H$1:$H$6 as the list of values for the drop down.

Output range contains formulae which effectively implement the rules noted in screenshot.

Different formulae are possible to implement slightly different rules relating the outputs to the inputs.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this tomorrow and will get back to you. Thanks again for your time!